# Sequelize - how to include a custom column details

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have 2 tables: **User** and **Follower**

The basic schema looks like this:

### User Table

```
var User = sequelize.define(
    "User",
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      username: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    {
      timestamps: true,
      tableName: "users",
      underscored: true
  ); 

  //Associations;
  User.associate = function(models) {
      User.hasMany(models.Follower, {
        constraints: false,
        onDelete: "cascade",
        hooks: true
      })
  };
```

### Follower Table

```
var Follower = sequelize.define(
    "Follower",
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      follower_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        foreignKey: true
      },
      following_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        foreignKey: true
      }
    },
    {
      timestamps: true,
      tableName: "followers",
      underscored: true
    }
  ); 

  //Associations;
  Follower.associate = function(models) {
    Follower.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: "following_id",
      constraints: false
    }),
    Follower.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: "follower_id",
      constraints: false
    });
  };
```

I want get a list of followers for a user but I want to show the user they are following and now their own data in.

I am currently running this procedure:

```
const following = await models.Follower.findAndCountAll({
    attributes: models.Follower.fields,
    where: { follower_id: user_id },
    include:[
      {
        model: models.User,
        attributes: models.User.fieldsPublic,
        required: yes
      }
    ]
})
```

The issue is that the `include` is returning the current user and not the user details of the person they are following.

Essentially the join seems to be between `User.id` = `Follower.follower_id`

How can I get it to `include` and join with `User.id` = `Follower.following_id`

Answer (score 1):

You can add `as` both in your Model definition and include to be able to define which foreign key should be used ([docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#foreign-keys))

So do:

```
Follower.associate = function(models) {
    Follower.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: "following_id",
      as: 'following',
      constraints: false
    }),
    Follower.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: "follower_id",,
      as: 'follower',
      constraints: false
    });
  };
```

and

```
...
include:[
      {
        model: models.User,
        attributes: models.User.fieldsPublic,
        as: 'follower'
        required: yes
      }
    ]
...
```

---

**Alternatively**, you can remove `required: yes` and use the `where` attribute to define the join condition

Furthermore, include seems to have an `on` attribute that is said to be similar to `where` (according to the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll)), but I was unable to find an example.